# sort data based on the date in api : react :js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make datewise table here only every data is shown in a single row I want it to show data based on each date. I have provided the codesandbox example of the problem
thanx in advance

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-kare-3qdmg?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

In your JSX code under the table body you have only one `<tr>` tag, so it renders a single row in any case.

```
<tbody>
    <tr style={{ background: "#ffffff1c 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box" }}>
        <td style={styles.tdFirst}></td>
        <td style={styles.td}>
            {medicinexc.map((personData, index) => {
                return <div key={index}>{personData.name}</div>;
            })}
        </td>
  {//...}
```

You need to use the `medicinexc` collection right under `<tbody>` level, and generate as many `<tr>` tags as you have dates in the collection.

Comment: this does not sort it by date

Comment: This is the code you provided. I am pointing you where your mistake is, and tell what you need to do to fix it ...

Comment: can u help me create a codesandbox example